# How to call anthore application in canvas using SurfaceView in android

Tags: android

I want to dipslay another application say `Test2` from `Test1` in a SurfaceView canvas. This is the code of the Thread's run function :

```
 public void run()
   {
    mcanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

    Intent LaunchIntent =  context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.test2");
    context.startActivity(LaunchIntent);

    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mcanvas); 
   }
```

This code invokes `Test2` , but not in the canvas. It replaces the entire application which is `Test1` with `Test2`.

I need help in this . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible. You cannot embed another app's activity into your own, whether using a `SurfaceView` or not, without substantial OS-level changes.

If you are the author of both Test1 and Test2, you are welcome to have Test2 prepare a `RemoteViews` with a UI and deliver that `RemoteViews` to Test1 by some means (e.g., broadcast). Test1 can then display that `RemoteViews`.